# In Excel, how can I ensure that N randomly selected columns from a named range have unique values across each row?

Tags: excel, vba, random

## Background

I am able to select values at random from a named range of strings in one sheet ("Sheet2") and populate a column called: `MyColumn` in a separate sheet ("Sheet1") using `=INDEX(aNamedRange,RANDBETWEEN(1,ROWS(aNamedRange)))`.

It looks like this:

```
|            MyColumn           |
|-------------------------------|
| RandomlySelectedValue_1, Col1 |
| RandomlySelectedValue_2, Col1 |
|              ...              |
| RandomlySelectedValue_N, Col1 |
```

I have made two other columns: `MyColumn2` and `MyColumn3`.

## Question

As `RandBetween` executes upon refresh is there a way to ensure that `RandomlySelectedValue_1, Col1` does not equal `RandomlySelectedValue_1, Col2?`.

In other words:

- This is the [expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULQQN.png), because all the randomly selected strings in the columns are distinct across the same row.
- This is [what's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6nA1.png), there is no check to prevent any randomly selected duplicates in the same row.

## What I've tried

I made this VBA Script:

```
Sub UniqueRandoms()
Do
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AB7").Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("FileName.xls!aNamedRange"), WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(Range("FileName.xls!aNamedRange"))))
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AC7").Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("FileName.xls!aNamedRange"), WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(Range("FileName.xls!aNamedRange"))))
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AD7").Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("FileName.xls!aNamedRange"), WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(Range("FileName.xls!aNamedRange"))))
Exit Do

Loop Until Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AB7").Value <> Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AC7").Value And Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AD7").Value <> Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AC7").Value And Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AB7").Value <> Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AD7").Value

End Sub
```

but I'm receiving a `Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error`.

Is the above script the best way to solve the problem or is there a simpler solution (that is potentially generalizable to any number of columns)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If the range were 1-6, say what you'd see on the face of the die, would it be non-random to have, say, three 4s come up?

Comment: Which worksheet is active when you run this VBA code? The 1004 would like raise if Sheet1 is active, but might raise if Sheet2 is active. Is the named range local to the worksheet or to the workbook?

Comment: Also worth mentioning: the random functions in Excel are pseudo-random at best. Also, no, there is nothing in the random functions that would prevent duplicates, although duplicates may be unlikely given a large enough range (e.g., `RandBetween(1,100000)` is less likely to have a dupe than `RandBetween(1,5)`, if you strictly need to prevent duplicates, then you'll need to implement some custom approach with VBA

Comment: So the named range is local to one sheet ("Sheet2"), but the columns I want to populate are in a separate sheet ("Sheet1").

Comment: @rajah9, I think it makes sense that 4 4 4 would come up infrequently but because MyColumn1, MyColumn2, and MyColumn3 have at least 400 cells below them, that situation occurs sometimes. I would like to prevent those situations from arising, if possible.

Comment: So create a collection, and a variable to hold your random number.  check to see if the number is in the collection, if not add it to the sheet and the collection, generate the next number, check if it is in the collection, if so generate again if not add to sheet and generate next number, rinse and repeat.  May want to have a duplicate counter checker so if you run into the same number x amount of times you can exit the routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went about creating something similar. I set my file up like this:

[image]

and I was able to take values in `A1:A7` and randomly place them in the columns at the top but specifically with no repeats.

I used a `collection` because the ability to add/remove items made it much easier to ensure I didn't double up. Once a value is output to the worksheet I removed it from the collection.

```
Sub RandomPlay()
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Set inputRange = Sheet1.Range("A1:A7")

    Dim inputCollection As Collection
    Set inputCollection = New Collection

    'populate collection with values from the input range
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In inputRange
        inputCollection.Add rng.Value
    Next rng

    Dim randomPick As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim result As Variant
    ReDim result(1 To inputCollection.Count)

    'pick randomly from collection > add to result array > remove from collection > repeat
    For i = 1 To inputCollection.Count
        randomPick = Int(Rnd() * inputCollection.Count) + 1
        result(i) = inputCollection(randomPick)
        inputCollection.Remove randomPick
    Next i

    Sheet1.Range("C2:I2").Value = result

    Set inputCollection = Nothing
End Sub
```

I'm not sure if this data setup is quite the same as yours but the method shown here should be helpful either way.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to adapt the code to my values!

Comment: No problem - if that answered your question please accept it by clicking the check mark to the left

Comment: This worked! I just added in a for loop with a variable called `Row` and concatenated it to the output range like so: `"C" & Row & ":" & "I" & Row` as I wanted to grow this range as much as possible.